# Azure functions queue trigger with managed identity

Tags: .net, azure, azure-functions, azure-queues, azure-functions-runtime

I created an isolated process Azure functions for queue trigger. Based on [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-output?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp) I created managed identify string using <CONNECTION_NAME_PREFIX>__queueServiceUri. This property works locally when I specify in local.settings.json. But it doesn't work when I specify in appsettings.json. Below is my program.cs code

```
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .AddCommandLine(args)
    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
    .Build();

var host = new HostBuilder().ConfigureHostConfiguration(config => {
config.AddConfiguration(configuration);
}).ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults().Build();
```

Function code:

```
 [Function("BlobQueueTrigger")]
    public async Task RunAsync([QueueTrigger("datablobqueue", Connection = "blobQueue")] string blobQueueItem)
    {}
```

Property in appsettings:

```
"blobQueue__queueServiceUri": "https://mydatastorage.queue.core.windows.net"
```

Comment: Have you tried setting them from azure portal ? in the configuration / app setting balde ?

Comment: yes. App setting in portal is working. Only appsettings.json property is not read.

Comment: are you using out of process function app (dotnet-isolated)?

Comment: correct. I use dotnet-isolated runtime.

Comment: let me give it a try

Comment: if you put a break point anywhere in your program.cs file, you see the error is thrown before hitting your code => i imagine it is due to the out of process mechanism

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-output?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-csharp#identity-based-connections) you referenced above, `blobQueue__queueServiceUri` must be defined as an *Environment Variable*, not in `appsettings.json`. This means you need to set it as an Application Setting [in the portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings?tabs=portal#settings). When working locally, values set in `local.settings.json` are indeed loaded as [Environment Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v2%2Ccmd#environment-variables)

Been a while since I dug into this, but I think it needs to access that value before it actually starts your process. Hence the custom configuration providers you have defined in `Program.cs` aren't yet loaded.

Comment: yes. App setting in portal is working. I would prefer the property within the code than in portal. If it is not possible within code , then portal is the only option.